# How can use zclip to copy content inside a DIV

Tags: php, jquery, html

Like to know how to use jQuery zclip to copy a content of a DIV tag instead of a textbox.

Ex: `<div class="txtdiv>` some text how can i copy the "some text" in to clipboard using zclip?

link to zclip http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if you have

```
<div id='copy'>Copy this</div>
<button id='copy-button'>copy</button>
```

you can do

```
$("#copy-button").zclip({
    path: "http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
    copy: function() {
        return $(this).prev().text();
    }
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/f4gZA/

Comment: I got a fiddle working: maybe you didn't set the right path of ZeroClipboard.js http://jsfiddle.net/f4gZA/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this - but it seems like you just need the correct selector

```
$('a#copy-description').zclip({
    path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy:$('div.txtdiv').text()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use anything with an id tag, I'm actually grabbing it via a AJAX postback, but its the same idea. This works in all browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //any jQuery/js Objects we want initialized
    if (typeof (PageInfo) === "undefined") {
        var PageInfo = {
            //stuff needed for communication process
            VehicleID: null,
            PostHTML: '',
            TemplateHTML: '',
            CopiedTemplateID: -1,
            TimeoutResult: false,
            isEbay: false
        };
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnCopy').each(function (i) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $(this).zclip({
                path: '/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
                copy: function () {
                    PageInfo.VehicleID = $('#<%=Me.ddlVehicleID.ClientID %>').val();
                    var yesno = $('input[name=chkEbay]:checked').val()
                    if (yesno == 'Yes') {
                        PageInfo.isEbay = true;
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        //do stuff
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        /do more stuff
                    });
                    return PageInfo.PostHTML;
                },
                afterCopy: function () {
                    $('#imgConfirm').show();
                }
            });
        });
```

And the html, I'm using asp.net but you should be able to use anything similar.

```
            <div style="float: left; margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                <b> Select a Vehicle:</b><br />
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlVehicleid" />
            </div>
```